# Home energy monitor install

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel, home-automation

Is a Neurio energy monitor compatible with a manufactured housing load center?

The load center, image below, doesn't seem to be officially supported however the approach seems sufficient. This kind of detail isn't readily available on the products [knowledge base](http://support.neur.io/customer/en/portal/articles/1838157-is-neurio-compatible-with-my-home-).

[image]

Comment: Do you have an installation manual handy you can link us?

Comment: [Neurio_W1_Quick_Install_Guide_-_2_phase.pdf](http://support.neur.io/customer/en/portal/articles/1847878-neurio-quick-install-guides) came with the unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it's a "manufactured housing load center" is irrelevant here -- from an electrical point of view, it's no different than any other load center with the same specifications.  So, simply follow the two phase instructions, although, for safety's sake, I would have the electric utility pull your meter for you for the duration of the panelboard work as residential panelboards don't separately guard the main breaker terminals, and installing the CTs requires working around them.  (It's not like a plastic piece over them'd be expensive...)

Comment: Thank you! It's safe to assume the equivalent of a "utility pulling the meter" would be to simply to pull the 50 amp cord connection from the RV/"tiny" home?

Comment: @user289394 -- for a cord connected situation, yes it would.  (Cord and plug connections are considered "disconnecting means" under the NEC all the time.)

Answer (score 1):

"Yep. It will work for any load. This is for a two phase setup (two lines / 240V). But it can be used for a single phase line as well." [1](https://www.amazon.com/these-devices-manufactured-center-connection-/forum/Fx1AO7AIN891JUZ/Tx3DPK5L7PXJ4Y4/1?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B0149EE5KS&cdEmailView=A13AK79WK9LDO1&cdShowComment=Mx2HMHXNG4G65N2&cdSort=oldest&cdThank=1&forceSignin=1&ref_=pe_623860_70668520#Mx2HMHXNG4G65N2)

"Assuming the 50A breaker are the main feeds, then yes you can install Neurio in the panel and power the unit using the 15A or 20A breakers." - neurio support